# Determining number of ColdFusion instances installed

Tags: coldfusion, server, multiple-instances

If anyone can help on this, I would appreciate it. I have two ColdFusion servers running, a testing environment and a live environment on separate machines. On my test machine, I know there is only one instance installed, and there is only one folder (1) in the wsconfig folder. On my live server, wsconfig has two folders in it (1 & 2). In other places, I have seen that indicates two instances installed, but I'm not sure how to confirm that. And, if there are two instances, help in uninstalling or at least disabling one would also be helpful.

As background, I have been fighting with hackers for several months replacing pages on our site with redirects. I think I have the server locked down now so they can't write to those directories, but I want to make sure they have not created a second instance, or are using a second instance, as a back door. Any thoughts or help would be appreciated.

Comment: This will probably be better received on http://serverfault.com/ as it's related more to server installation & configuration than programming. You might also ask on the CFML Slack Channel: https://cfml.slack.com/ (Join here:http://cfml-slack.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: The 'numbered' folders under wsconfig have to do with the 'connector' configuration, between ColdFusion engine and the websites (if you have more than one website on the same server). You might have only one CF instance running but if you configured 2 websites separately you will see two folders, each holding the configuration for one website. If, when you install CF you select "all websites" for the connector then you will only have one folder under wsconfig.

Comment: If you are on a windows machine, log on, launch the task manager and see what's running.

Comment: This might be a bit out there, but have you considered installing Fusion Reactor (http://www.fusion-reactor.com/)?  When you install it, it scans your system to see which of the CF instances you want to attach the service to.

Also, you can't go wrong with running a port scan on your box if you are worried about it being compromised.  If there's a second instance of CF, it has to be on some port between 0-65535.